# Solving functional equation for measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, functional-equations

In a problem I am working on, I get the following functional equality:
$$a(x)+b(y)=c(x+y)+d\left({x\over y}\right)+w(x,y)$$
Where $x,\ y>0$ and $a,\ b,\ c,\ d,\ w$ are real Borel measurable functions. Also, $w(x,y)$ can be written as $w(x,y)=K\left(\int_0^{x+y}e^{c(z)}{z}\ dz,\ \int_0^{x\over{x+y}}e^{d(z)}\ dz\right)=K(s,t)$ for some measurable function $K$.

Let $r>0$ then:
$$a(rx)+b(ry)=c(rx+ry)+a(x)+b(y)-c(x+y)-w(x,y)+w(rx,ry)$$
$$a_r(x)+b_r(y)=c_r(x+y)+w_r(x,y)$$
Where $a_r(x)=a(rx)-a(x)$, $b_r(x)=b(rx)-b(x)$, $c_r(x+y)=c(rx+ry)-c(x+y)$ and $w_r(x,y)=w(rx,ry)-w(x,y)$.

Consequently,
$$w_r(0,y)=b_r(y)-c_r(y)$$
$$w_r(x,0)=a_r(x)-c_r(x)$$

My goal is to know a solution technique to get a general form for $a,\ b,\ c,\ d$ given that I have a form for $K(s,t).$

For example if $K(s,t)=0$ then this becomes Olkin-Baker equation which has a nice solution.

Now if $K_{\alpha}(s,t)={(1-\alpha)-\alpha(1-\alpha)(1-s)(1-t)+2\alpha st \over \left(1-\alpha (1-s)(1-t)\right)^{3}}$ for $\alpha \in [-1,1]$

If $x=0$ then $t=0$ and $K_{\alpha}(s,0)={(1-\alpha)-\alpha(1-\alpha)(1-s) \over \left(1-\alpha (1-s)\right)^{3}}.$

And if $y=0$ then $t=1$ and $K_{\alpha}(s,1)={(1-\alpha)+2\alpha s}.$

So for $y=0$ we get $$a_r(x)-c_r(x)=2\alpha \left(\int_0^{rx}e^{c(z)}z\ dz\ -\int_0^x e^{c(z)}z\ dz\right)$$

And similarly for $x=0$ 
$$b_r(y)-c_r(y)=K_{\alpha}\left(\int_0^{ry}e^{c(z)}{z}\ dz,\ 0\right)-K_{\alpha}\left(\int_0^{y}e^{c(z)}{z}\ dz,\ 0\right)$$

And the original equation $$a_r(x)+b_r(y)=c_r(x+y)+K_{\alpha}\left(\int_0^{rx+ry}e^{c(z)}{z}\ dz,\ \int_0^{x\over{x+y}}e^{d(z)}\ dz\right)-K_{\alpha}\left(\int_0^{x+y}e^{c(z)}{z}\ dz,\ \int_0^{x\over{x+y}}e^{d(z)}\ dz\right)$$

I would get equations involving integrals. What techniques I can use to solve such equations?

Any links to papers that deal with similar problems are appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  For any functions $a,b,c,d$, there is obviously a unique function $w$ that makes the equation hold.

Comment: My aim is to get general solutions for $a, b, c, d$ given a functional form for $w(x,y)$ in terms of integrals of $c, d.$